# SQL sum function with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using MsSQL and I want to add some values where some conditions are met.
Is it possible to use WHERE clause in the sum() function? Or is there an equivalent function to the excel SUMIF().

Comment: Post your query and we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN YourCondition=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: +1 over Oded's method, this allows you to group the results which (I guess) would be more useful to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The `SUM` aggregate will only operate on the result set constrained by the `WHERE` clause.

In other words, yes, this is fine.

```
SELECT SUM(days)
FROM myTable
WHERE something = another
```

Comment: sorry I didn't explain but I don't to use the condition in the where clause

Comment: @Mhretabk - Well, where are you using a condition then? Posting the query in your question would have left no doubt.